# Weebly header links encoding error for arabic site

Tags: encoding, arabic, weebly

My arabic website is created using weebly, today when i wanted to edited any page i found the page I am editing is with encoded page title! even after changing the title again to be arabic, nothing is happening and stil the title is encoded!

[image]

I checked my code and it is ok! :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

And this is the website: www.elbosna.com

Is there any solution to this wired problem that appeared only today?

Answer (score 0):

The strings that you send to the function `initPublishedFlyoutMenus` are encoded incorrectly. Instead of strings like `"title":"&amp;#1575;&amp;#1604;..` your code should contain strings like `"title":"&#1575;&#1604;..` without the `&amp;` escape code.

[image]

Some of the titles in the navigation menu are encoded correctly, so check the configuration on your side, what is the difference between correct and incorrect menu items. It may be something with the tools you use to edit the site's configuration